# How do i check that which runtime OCI, CRI-O , Containerd or runc is used by me?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, runtime

I have deployed pods using kubectl apply command and I can see pods running:

```
$kubectl describe pod  test-pod -n sample  | grep -i container
Containers:
    Container ID:   containerd://ce6cd9XXXXXX69538XXX
  ContainersReady   True
```

Can I say that it's using contained runtime technology? How do I verify the runtime used by containers.

I am also getting some errors like below in pod:

```
kubectl logs test-pod -n sample

'docker.images' is not supported: Cannot fetch data: Get http://1.28/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory.
```

Is it because I am not using docker runtime?

Comment: You can you kubectl get nodes -o wide. You should see the container runtime then

Answer (score 2):

As i already mentioned in a comment the command is

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

It will returns the container runtime for each node.